# How to use multiple imputed data for survey estimation?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I'm trying to calculate population mean, median, (etc, descriptive analysis) using multiple imputed data. However, the example that I found in sources were regression and then pool them into one estimate.

I was wondering if it would be valid to combine the m imputed datasets produced from one dataset into one using mean, to then be used for whatever analysis there is.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if it would be valid to combine the m imputed datasets produced from one dataset into one using mean, to then be used for whatever analysis there is

No, this would be a bad idea. Part of the reason for doing multiple imputation in the first place is that it creates variance between imputations. If you combine them with mean values then you lose this and will get invalid inference.

The correct approach is to run your analysis odel on each imputed dataset and then combine/pool the results using Rubin's rules. If you are using the `mice` package in R then it can do the pooling for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not please let us know why so that it can be improved.

Comment: Robert, what might be your suggestion to me if I want to use (an MCMC based) MI for SI purpose? That is, say I'm not interested in estimating statistics errors, I just want a _single_ dataset giving stats values (say, correlations in it) either less biased or more accurate w.r.t. the population figures. For that, shall I (i) just produce or take a single dataset in MI, or (ii) produce m datasets and, for each missing value, select independently and randomly one value from its m imputants, (iii) do some other form or hybridization or pooling between the m imputation versions, (iv) else way?.